# Binding error from the treeview control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I faced one issue and I would really appreciate it if you could provide any advice for this.

Error message:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')

I have a treeview control (C# WPF .NET 4.0), and several items are added into this treeview by using datatemplate in xaml or manually, and both uses data binding.

When new data structure is received, I need to clean all items in treeview and regenerate new one by `treeview_Control.Items.Clear()` and it seems working fine from GUI point of view, but when I see output window on Visual Studio it shows several error messages as like above.

I've tried to search for a solution and tried several methods but no luck yet. Someone just recommended to just ignore this error message, but I just really want to clear this up.

If you have any idea, please help me for this.

Comment: can you share your xaml and viewmodel/codebehind ?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, This is a comment but I cant fit in the comment section

Can you try add a `ItemContainerStyle` on the TreeView and see if it fixes the error, we had the same issue in a `ListView` and this was the only workaround we could find to remove the error.

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. This addition to ItemContainerStyle makes no difference at all to me. (Which I'm not totally unhappy about. Didn't really want any more XAML workaround hacks like this in my code...)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution that works for me. I first added a global style to my App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
</Style>
```

I also had to add the following to my TreeView:

```
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"
        TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">         
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For some reason, the BasedOn attribute was the missing piece in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.When I was removing items from treeview via ViewModel ,I was receiving same harmless error messages.
I have defined style for TreeViewItem in UserControl.Resources.
In that style are also setters for content alignments.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem" x:Key="myTreeViewItemStyle"
             BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    ...</Style>
```

What did help to me was addint ItemContainerStyle referenc in TreeView.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myTreeViewItemStyle}">
```

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. I'll just have to continue ignoring these error messages.